# AngularJS Toastr fadeIn fadeOut

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toastr

i have a service code like ;

```html
<script>
var pop = function (type, message, callbackfn,duration) {
        toaster.pop({
            type: type,
            body: message,
            showCloseButton: true,
            timeout: duration,
            positionClass: "toast-top-full-width",
            onHideCallback: callbackfn,
            hideDuration : 1000,
            hideMethod: 'slideUp'
        });

</script>
```

but my toaster is not fading in or fading out.
My AngularJS toastr version is : 0.4.15 which option should i add in pop method to get fadeOut feature ?

Comment: Did you add its CSS?

Comment: And 0.4.15 is pretty old latest one is 1.2.0 I suggest to update it

Comment: @Michelem yes added css, will try update

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Angular port, but the original can be played with [here](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) . This would suggest the properties your concerned with are:

- "showMethod": "fadeIn"
- "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
- "showDuration": "300"
- "hideDuration": "3000"
- "timeOut": "2000"

  1. Is your toast showing at all?
  2. Have you confirmed that your type, message, and duration variables are populated at the point of calling?

Comment: <script>
        toaster.pop({
            type: 'error',
            body: 'dummyMessage',
            showCloseButton: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            positionClass: "toast-top-full-width",
            onHideCallback: null,
            hideDuration : 1000,
            hideMethod: 'fadeOut'
        });

</script>

Yes my toast is showing. And when i confirm the options field it is still not working.

Comment: you definitely have the css included?

http://plnkr.co/edit/mVR4P4?p=info

Here's an example using Angular version. What happens if you use defaults and just try something like:

toaster.pop('success', "title", "text");

Comment: also current version is 1.2.1. Can you upgrade to latest?

Comment: when you say 'no fadeout' do you mean it just disappears abruptly, or that it doesn't disappear at all?

Also, are you able to upgrade as perhaps this is a known bug, you appear to be running quite an old version.

Comment: it is disappearing suddenly without fading . Yeah probably it is about the version. Thank you.

Comment: also, AngularJS-Toaster states it requires AngularJS v1.2.6 or higher and angular-animate for the CSS3 transformations. So make sure you get angular-animate!